# Get Request works in postman but not work in flutter giving 400 error

Tags: flutter, dart, https, postman, http-status-code-400

I am sending a get request with JSON body and bearer token it is working fine in Postman but it is not working in Flutter code and gives 400 bad requests with this response:

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-2460b88e437fb2021b6249f0a3d0abf0-3f2e0cef2e5fefa3-00",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
        ],
        "signIn": [
            "The signIn field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my flutter code:

```
final body = userData.toJsonLogin();

var headersList = {
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

var request =
    http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://192.168.0.128/api/Profile'));

request.body = body;

request.headers.addAll(headersList);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
} else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

How can I solve this problem the API is provided by my senior and I can't change it.

Comment: Are you in same network?? and is the device used for debugging connected to same network?

Comment: yes I am on the same network other endpoints of this API are working correctly

Comment: can you provide a sample of the request body ?

Comment: {"userid": "String", "password": "String"}

Comment: do you have any cookies to be passed while hitting the api?

Comment: no, I doesn't required any cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in the header your header map

```
var headersList = {
 'Accept': '*/*',
 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
};
```

And correct one is

```
var headersList = {
 'Accept': '*/*',
 'authorization': 'Bearer $token', // Authorization -> authorization
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
};
```

let me know if the issue resolved.

Comment: no, it doesn't work